# Outlook Receiving Mails in HTML Code

Tags: php, html, email, outlook

In my project i have done some email code to receive the order details, 1 mail to admin and other mail for user..

But some users and admins are receiving the emails with html code.. I checked in many ways with gmail, webmail.. All are displaying good.. Finally I tested with outlook and in outlook mail was getting in html code.. By enquiring the users they said that they r using outlook.. So that issue was with outlook I think so..

Can anyone help me to solve this issue.. Here is the source code which was used for displaying in email message.

```
    $to = $obj_check_out->email;
    $subject = "NEW YORK PRODUCT ORDER";
    $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: Instyle Customer Accounts <vamsi@mail.com>" . "\r\n";
    $message = '<table width="100%" align="center">
        <tbody><tr><td bgcolor="#393939">
            <br>
            <br>
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="650" border="0" align="center">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td width="10" bgcolor="#efefef">
                        <img src="images/newsletter/top_left.jpg" class="CToWUd">
                    </td>
                    <td width="630" height="92" bgcolor="#efefef" background="images/newsletter/top_bg.jpg">
                        <table width="630">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="514">
                                    <font color="#333333" style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:12px">
                                    <br>
                                    <b><a target="_blank" href="#"><span class="il">NEWYORK</span>.COM</a> ORDER CONFIRMATION</b> &nbsp; &nbsp;</font> 
                                    <font color="#333333" style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:10px">[ DATE: '.$response["date_ordered"].' ]</font>
                                </td>
                                <td width="104" align="right">
                                    <font color="#333333" style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:12px">
                                    <br>
                                    <b>ORDER#:</b></font>
                                    <font color="#333333" style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:10px"> '.$response["order_log_id"].'</font>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <br>
                    </td>
                    <td width="10" bgcolor="#efefef">
                        <img src="images/newsletter/top_right.jpg" class="CToWUd">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#efefef">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td bgcolor="#efefef">
                        <font color="#333333">
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" width="630" border="0">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td height="35" bgcolor="#767676" background="images/newsletter/bar_bg.jpg" colspan="2">
                                    <font color="#ffffff" style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:12px">
                                    &nbsp;<b>SHIPPING DETAILS</b></font>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="170">&nbsp;<font style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:10px"><b>Name :</b></font></td>
                                <td width="452"><font style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:10px">'.$response["firstname"].' '.$response["lastname"].'</font></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td>&nbsp;<font style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:10px"><b>Address :</b></font></td>
                                <td><font style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:10px">'.$response["ship_address1"].' '.$response["ship_address2"].'</font></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>&nbsp;<font style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:10px"><b>City :</b></font></td>
                                <td><font style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:10px">'.$response["ship_city"].'</font></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>&nbsp;<font style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:10px"><b>State :</b></font></td>
                                <td><font style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:10px">'.$response["ship_state"].'</font></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>&nbsp;<font style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:10px"><b>Country :</b></font></td>
                                <td><font style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:10px">'.$response["ship_country"].'</font></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>&nbsp;<font style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:10px"><b>Zip :</b></font></td>
                                <td><font style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:10px">'.$response["ship_zipcode"].'</font></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>&nbsp;<font style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:10px"><b>Phone :</b></font></td>
                                <td><font style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:10px">'.$response["telephone"].'</font></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>&nbsp;<font style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:10px"><b>Email :</b></font></td>
                                <td><font style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:10px"><a target="_blank" href="mailto:'.$response["email"].'">'.$response["email"].'</a></font></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>&nbsp;<font style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:10px"><b>Courier :</b></font></td>
                                <td><font style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:10px">'.$response["courier"].'</font></td>
                            </tr>

                        </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <br>


                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" width="630" border="0">  
                            <tbody><tr>
                                <td background="images/newsletter/bar_bg.jpg" align="center"><font color="#a1a1a1" style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:11px"><b>Thumb</b></font></td>
                                <td background="images/newsletter/bar_bg.jpg" align="center"><font color="#a1a1a1" style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:11px"><b>Item</b></font></td>
                                <td background="images/newsletter/bar_bg.jpg" align="center"><font color="#a1a1a1" style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:11px"><b>Style Number</b></font></td>
                                <td background="images/newsletter/bar_bg.jpg" align="center"><font color="#a1a1a1" style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:11px"><b>Size</b></font></td>
                                <td background="images/newsletter/bar_bg.jpg" align="center"><font color="#a1a1a1" style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:11px"><b>Color</b></font></td>   
                                <td background="images/newsletter/bar_bg.jpg" align="center"><font color="#a1a1a1" style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:11px"><b>Quantity</b></font></td>
                                <td background="images/newsletter/bar_bg.jpg" align="center"><font color="#a1a1a1" style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:11px"><b>Price</b></font></td>
                                <td background="images/newsletter/bar_bg.jpg" align="center"><font color="#a1a1a1" style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:11px"><b>Subtotal</b></font></td>
                            </tr>
                            '.$ordermsg.'
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right" colspan="7"><font style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:12px">Grand-Total : </font></td>
                                <td align="right"><font style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:12px">$'.$grandtotal.'</font></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right" colspan="7"><font style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:9px">( For countries other than United State, you will be contacted by customer service for shipping fees ) &nbsp; </font></td>
                                <td align="center"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" colspan="8"><font style="color:red;font-family:Tahoma;font-size:9px"><br><br>* NOTE: Your order was received and will ship according to the availability notice on product page. &nbsp; </font><br></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody></table>
                        <table width="630" align="center" style="border-top:1px solid black">
                            <tbody><tr>
                                <td width="630" align="center">
                                    <font color="#333333" style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:10px">
                                        <span class="il">Instyle</span> <span class="il">New</span> <span class="il">York</span>
                                        230 West 38th Street
                                        <span class="il">New</span> <span class="il">York</span>, NY 10018
                                        PHONE: 212-840-0846 ext 22 &nbsp; EMAIL <a target="_blank" href="mailto:vamsi@gmail.com">info@<span class="il">company</span>.com</a>
                                    </font>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="630" align="center">
                                    <font color="#333333" style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:10px">
                                        Purchaser agrees to abide by the <a target="_blank" href="#"><span class="il">company</span>.com</a> return policy.
                                    </font>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody></table>
                        </font>
                    </td>
                    <td bgcolor="#efefef">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="images/newsletter/bottom_left.jpg" class="CToWUd"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/newsletter/bottom_bg.jpg" class="CToWUd"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/newsletter/bottom_right.jpg" class="CToWUd"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
            <br><br>
        </td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>';
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

The email in outlook getting the same html code of $message with containing order details..

Thanks

Comment: without knowing how you're sending `mail()`, there's not enough code here. Make sure you are indeed sending out as HTML and not plain text. RTM http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Here is the mail().. mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers); @Fred-ii-

Comment: please edit your question with the full mail and headers used for it and not in comments. thanks

Comment: another thing; `<img src="images/newsletter/bottom_left.jpg" class="CToWUd">` those only work locally. You want to use `<img src="http://example.com/images/newsletter/bottom_left.jpg" class="CToWUd">`

Comment: Yes I changed my question.. Okay.. I removed links.. Basically there was full links for images in code.. @Fred-ii-

Comment: also, if you don't have a `<!doctype html>` declaration and `<body>` tags etc, then that too will contribute to the problem. Or that people using Outlook have their settings set to not display HTML and images. I have seen that happen quite often before. So, this could be a local problem. Therefore, you need to include a seperate header as TEXT only. Use Phpmailer. That should solve everything.

Comment: Was there any reference to know how to use phpmailer @Fred-ii-

Comment: Everything is in my answer below.

Comment: If you believe that the answer that was posted solved and/or answered the question, then please mark it as solved in order to close the question properly. Otherwise, it will remain in Stack's unanswered category.

Answer (score 1):

If your code doesn't contain a valid `<!doctype html>` declaration and `<body>` tags etc, then that could contribute to the problem.

People using Outlook (or other similar mail clients) may have their settings set to not display HTML and images. I have seen that happen quite often before.

- This stands at being a local issue and you have **no control** over that.

Therefore, you need to include a seperate header as TEXT only which is the usual norm when sending mail.

Use Phpmailer or Swiftmailer. That should solve everything.

References:

- https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer
- http://phpmailer.worxware.com/
- http://swiftmailer.org/

and read the documentation on its implementation.

Other options are to use services such as MailChimp, Constant Contact etc. which work well and are services that are used widely and are already setup to handle both HTML and plain text formats.

- http://mailchimp.com/
- http://www.constantcontact.com/